# is App Indexing for iOS working?

Tags: ios, android-app-indexing

Im trying to add the app Indexing, but the method `[GSDDeepLink handleDeepLink:url];` is returning the same gsd-MY_URL:// when it's supposed to sanitize it to MY_URL://.
As you can see here, [App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app) the snippet is really simple.
My code is the same as in the docs,

```
DLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
NSURL *sanitizedURL = [GSDDeepLink handleDeepLink:url];
DLog(@"sanitizedURL: %@", sanitizedURL);
```

That last sanitizedURL, returns the whole URL, not sanitized

Since it's available on a limited release I'm not sure if the method should work or am I doing something wrong.

I already have deep linking from my webpage, and it works perfectly, and this should be no pain, but it is.
Any info on this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Any update on this issue ?
I'm having the same problem..